# Where was the J-20 design stolen from?

Tags: fighter, china

Lets clear the Question Detalis
Once upon a time, I heard something like "China hacked X country and stole aircraft designs" and rest of the news were about an newer Chinese jet
Now, It looks somewhat like the F-22 Raptor
Now the last section (Video under here) was put as a joke
But admit it , even though it looks like an joke, It looks extremely the same ! (It also looks like J10)

Comment: Your title takes for granted that it was "stolen", while the body of the question does not. Which of the two?

Comment: Any answer to this question can only be speculation. China will never admit stealing plans and proving they did is virtually impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Where was the J-20 design stolen from?**

There are various unsubstantiated reports circulating which link the J-20 design to

- [Theft of F-35 engine design details](http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35687.pdf)
- [Theft of F-35 design data](https://www.reuters.com/article/usa-fighter-hacking/theft-of-f-35-design-data-is-helping-u-s-adversaries-pentagon-idUSL2N0EV0T320130619)
- [Jailing of Chinese businessman Su Bin for espionage](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/chinese-hack-us-military-su-bin)
- [Chinese National Pleads Guilty to Conspiring to Hack into U.S. Defense Contractors’ Systems to Steal Sensitive Military Information](https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/chinese-national-pleads-guilty-conspiring-hack-us-defense-contractors-systems-steal-sensitive)

> A criminal complaint filed in 2014 and subsequent indictments filed in Los Angeles charged Su, a China-based businessman in the aviation and aerospace fields, for his role in the criminal conspiracy to steal military technical data, including data relating to the C-17 strategic transport aircraft and certain fighter jets produced for the U.S. military.

But overall, the suggestion that the J-20 *airframe* design was stolen is not well supported.

---

> **One theory states, that the design was taken from a videogame? Could that be true?**

No.

Comment: That "Video game part" wasnt there, someone edited without knowing the fact that, that was an "joke"

Answer (score 5):

When posting such questions you might want to give more context; who is *everyone* and where are they saying that it has been copied.

The J-20 is based on an earlier project called J-XX, dating back to the 1990s. It is very doubtful that it has been copied from a computer game, as the design process of a military aircraft cares little about the visual looks and more about the aerodynamics and performance. A computer game on the other hand cares nothing about these aspects, and **only** about how it looks.